# How to rollback what an action did on sqlite database using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, rollback

I am updating a database table before requesting some json data from a web service. Some times response fail. If this type of occasion ho can i rollback  update operation using objectivec.

```
-(void)syncPhoneDBWithData:(NSData *)data{

NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithJSONData:data];

if ([dictionary count]!= 0) {
    NSArray *ticketsArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"tickets"];


    for (NSDictionary *ticketDict in ticketsArray) {

        Ticket *ticketToStore = [[Ticket alloc]init];

        ticketToStore.ticketID = [ticketDict objectForKey:@"ticketID"];
        ticketToStore.ticketTitle = [ticketDict objectForKey:@"ticketTitle"];
        ticketToStore.numberOfAdults = [ticketDict objectForKey:@"numberOfAdults"];
        ticketToStore.numberOfChildren = [ticketDict objectForKey:@"numberOfChildren"];
        ticketToStore.redeemed = [ticketDict objectForKey:@"redeemed"];
        ticketToStore.syncStatus = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

        if ([DBConnect isExistingTicket:ticketToStore.ticketID]) {

            [DBConnect updateTicketRedeemStatus:ticketToStore];
        }else{

            [DBConnect insertNewTicket:ticketToStore];
        }

    }


}else{

    NSLog(@"======================Empty============================");
}
```

}

```
+ (NSString *)insertNewTicket:(Ticket *)ticket{
NSString *lastInsertedTicketId = @"";

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];


sqlite3 *database;

if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sqlStatement = "insert into tickets (ticket_id , ticket_title , adults , children ,  redeem_status , sync_status, redeemed_dateTime ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)    {

        sqlite3_bind_text   ( compiledStatement, 1, [ticket.ticketID UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text   ( compiledStatement, 2, [ticket.ticketTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int    ( compiledStatement, 3, [ticket.numberOfAdults intValue] );
        sqlite3_bind_int    ( compiledStatement, 4, [ticket.numberOfChildren intValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_text   ( compiledStatement, 5, [ticket.redeemed UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int    ( compiledStatement, 6, [ticket.syncStatus intValue] );
        sqlite3_bind_int    ( compiledStatement, 7, [ticket.redeemedDate timeIntervalSince1970]);

    }


    if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE ) {
        NSLog( @"add new Ticket Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
    }else{
        lastInsertedTicketId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld",sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database)];
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}

sqlite3_close(database);


return lastInsertedTicketId;
```

}

Comment: You need to create a transaction and then either commit or rollback at the end.

Comment: thanks @trojanfoe, Could you explain with a piece of code.

Comment: There is quite a bit of info already floating about; just google "slqlite transaction" and you'll find plenty.

Answer (score 1):

Use CoreData (wrapped into [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)) and **undo**. :)